# I have an input of type range aka the slider input. I want to add css to it

Tags: html, css, input, colors, webkit

I want the slider to have two colors, one color for when it goes down and the other color for when it goes up. Please see picture below. However, right now the slider color is the full width.

I also want to make the slider circle itself a different color aka the thumb.

So far this is my code

```
     <div class="slider-info">
        <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
      </div>
```

```
input.slider {
      width: 100%;
    }


    /* Change the color of the thumb on webkit-based browsers */
    input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      cursor: move;
      transform: scale(2);
      position: relative;
      bottom: 2.5px;
    }

    /* Change the color of the track on webkit-based browsers */
    input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
      position: relative;
      background-color: #A4FFAF;
      border-radius: 3px;
      padding: 0px;
      height: 10px;

    }
```

I want to achieve this look, but with no libraries. Is it possible to do it with plain css and HTML? This is my pen thus far https://codepen.io/Victor-Villacis/pen/gOjKQrN

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a code like this to make it look similar to the picture, just play with the properties.

Here is an interesting pen you can use as a reference:
https://codepen.io/brandonmcconnell/pen/oJBVQW

```css
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

 html input[type="range"] {
     outline: 0;
     border: 0;
     width: 400px;
     max-width: 100%;
     margin: 24px 0 16px;
     transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out;
     padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
}
 @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) {
     html input[type="range"] {
         overflow: hidden;
         height: 40px;
         -webkit-appearance: none;
         background-color: #24232c;
    }
     html input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
         height: 45px;
         -webkit-appearance: none;
         color: #a4ffaf;
         transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out;
    }
     html input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
         width: 40px;
         -webkit-appearance: none;
         height: 50px;
         cursor: ew-resize;
         background: #fff;
         box-shadow: -340px 0 0 320px #1597ff, inset 0 0 0 40px #1597ff;
         border-radius: 50%;
         transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out;
         position: relative;
    }
     html input[type="range"]:active::-webkit-slider-thumb {
         background: #fff;
         box-shadow: -340px 0 0 320px #1597ff, inset 0 0 0 3px #1597ff;
    }
}
 html input[type="range"]::-moz-range-progress {
     background-color: #a4ffaf;
}
 html input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track {
     background-color: #9a905d;
}
 html input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-lower {
     background-color: #43e5f7;
}
 html input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-upper {
     background-color: #9a905d;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

 
  <p>Custom range slider:</p>
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```